# Scroll snap on iOS – but preserve automatic shrinking of address bar and hiding of toolbar

Tags: css, mobile

### AIM

To have a very long web page appear in iOS browsers using CSS scroll snapping.

### PROBLEM

My own attempt and examples written up in css-tricks work but they stop iOS's automatic shrinking of the address bar and hiding of the toolbar when the user scrolls. This is quite a loss of screen real estate on a smaller phone.

### TEST EQUIPMENT

iOS 14.2, iPhone SE (1st generation). Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

### TEST CASES

https://codepen.io/maxakohler/full/JBjROd
https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/full/yLLqqgP
(both written about in this article: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)

### TEST CODE

#### Parent

```
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: scroll;
scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

#### Children

```
height: 1px;
background-color: transparent;
scroll-snap-align: end;
scroll-snap-stop: always
```

Many thanks. 1st ever web development post.

Comment: Sorry nobody ever answered your first ever post. I'm trying to use snap scrolling in Safari and in iOS 15 it's even more complicated because the URL bar appears and disappears. It seems they don't correctly calculate the new position considering the final state of the URL bar.

Comment: I didn't found a solution yet. However, I also noticed that I got a very long scrollbar that didn't indicate progress. I could solve it based on this article. 
https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

I hoped it could solve the status bar issue too, but it doesn't.

Comment: I noticed applying ```-webkit-fill-available``` actually breaks scroll-snapping on Chrome. So I only apply it on iOS by wrapping it in this supports hack: ```@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none)```

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue and suspect it is related to the fact that the scroll container removes scrolling from the main document window. Tricky to remedy when the scrolling blocks are inside a container. Be interested to know if anybody has resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

So I also experienced issues getting `scroll-snap-type` to work on iOS while maintaining the shrinking address bar and hiding the toolbar. After quite a bit of testing it became clear the scroll has to be attached to the main `html` element to trigger this behaviour. Fixing the height of a container within the `html` element, even the `body` element, to `100vh` will stop any scroll effect taking place on the top `html` element.

This sample html code is working for me on Safari (both iOS and desktop), as well as Chrome and Firefox:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iOS Friendly Scroll Snap Page</title>

     <style type="text/css">
    * {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
     html { 
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        scroll-padding-top: 50px;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0;
    }
    header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height:50px;
        top:0;
        background-color: green;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    section {
        height:100vh;
        background-color: blue;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .first {
        padding-top: 65px;
    }
    .second {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .last {
        background-color: pink;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <header> Header </header>
        <section class="first"> Section One </section>
        <section class="second"> Section Two </section>
        <section class="third"> Section Three </section>
        <section class="last"> Section Four </section>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Bit late to the party, but I hope it helps. Would be interested to know if anyone can find problems with it.

Comment: Can't even remember how I was going to use this but I can confirm that the code you have written does indeed allow the address bar to hide on my iPhone SE (1st generation) within iOS 15.7.3

Comment: Thanks for this, good sir!   I was trying to my more complex appto have this same div structure and reproduce the success, which i did.  One thing I did notice that may be helpful to note is that the body tag (and perhaps other intermediate tags??) cannot have ANY overflow "hidden" set, even in the x dimension, or else the scroll snap behavior doesn't work.  I'm going to experiment and see if if body is a special case or if any intermediate tags w overflow hidden break it (my guess).